# Programmable IO

Tags: multiplexer

I have three bit input and would like to have a three bit output programmed for the input combinations.

```
000 - 000
001 - 001
010 - 010
011 - 001
100 - 100
101 - 001
110 - 010
111 - 001
```

Is there a chip available so that we can program and work accordingly to the above inputs. Also possible that it can take power from the input, rather than external power to get it to work?

Comment: You can build such circuit using basic gates too... Plot a K-Map and design circuit!

Comment: You don't need a K-Map because the first output contains only a single product term, the second just has two product terms in which one variable is an obvious don't care, and the third output just mirrors the third input. I algebraically converted the product terms to NAND and NOR form in a couple of step and went straight to gates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a truly single-chip solution, use a CMOS dual 4:1 multiplexer. If you don't have a power supply, it can be powered via its input-protection diodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTaWRE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Dave. That is awesome. Input-Protection Diodes also is a good solution for the PS.

Comment: I have added the complete circuit here, Please suggest if I have missed something. https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/sm8v2z/3-phase-input-to-single-phase-output/

Comment: [Here's](https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/m2xfeb/3-phase-selector/) a cleaned-up version. You really want to keep the low-voltage stuff isolated from the mains.

Comment: One thing to watch out for with the multiplexer approach in general is that a typical multiplexer's output will be unspecified any time either "select" input hasn't either held a valid high for a few nanoseconds or held a valid low for a few nanoseconds, *even if the output would have the same result with that input high as it would have with it low*.

Comment: unspecified - Will that be low or high? . If that is high it is a serious problem. If that is neutral or low voltage mean less than 3v then it should be fine.

Comment: @Kannaiyan: Unspecified means, among other things, that the fact that the chips made by one particular manufacturer in one particular week behaves a certain way does not imply that any other chips will do likewise.  If it is imperative that the downstream circuit not have any glitches if S1 is low and S0 transitions between high and low, some other circuit might be more appropriate.

Comment: I'm getting to test within a week or two as soon as the components arrive. Will keep updated on how it works. I'm also getting the PIC12F683 as suggested in one of the solution, to see which is more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to program your answer  rather than built a discrete decoder try one of the 8 pin PIC chips such as the as the 12F683 which has 6 I/O lines  for example (others are available).

Use it with the internal oscillator and set for three inputs and three outputs. Some of the pins are allocated other (programmable) functions but for this application you can ignore that. Power requirements are fairly minimal so battery operation would give a long operational life.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Much appreciated. This seems to be ideal for me. Programming every chip and testing it to make sure it works as expected seems a problem on scaling. Will fix this as solution if there is no single chip option.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this: -

```
000 - 000
001 - 001
010 - 010
011 - 001
100 - 100
101 - 001
110 - 010
111 - 001
```

Clearly there is only a single bit set in the answer and the 3rd bit always follows the input so if this is set then the 1st and 2nd bit should be forced low. In addition, if the 2nd bit is set it should also kill the first bit: -

[image]

A, a is 3rd input/output

B, b is 2nd input/output

C, c is 1st input/output

The circuit is indicative of functionality only but it will work and can be easily improved for higher switching speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Tested using DC solver for all input combinations:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDsjZO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: For the 000 input how do you assure that all the outputs will also be 000? With 000 input there is no pseudo "Vcc" to bias on the various FET gates that need to be "On" to force outputs to "000". I'd say this circuit requires some attention - or at least specify that the circuit cannot be powered from the inputs for all combinations of the inputs.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I thought about maybe using weak pulldowns for that. Only OUT1 and OUT2 need that since OUT3 is the same net as IN3. I can take a look at it some hours from now in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Two DPDT relays meet the requirements:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzWNgT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: Now that you've shown us that what you really want to do is select one of three phases of line voltage for a single-phase load, this much simpler circuit will work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUFgj0.png)</sup>

Comment: Can we have this as a SSR relay with higher ampere rating for this question? That can avoid all needs of other low voltage circuitry. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70718/three-phase-input-to-single-phase-output

Comment: Yes, now that I see what you're actually up to, you can simply use relays that have coils rated for mains voltage. In fact, you can use a much simpler arrangement of contacts.

Comment: That is awesome and so simple. Phases will not have the constant voltage, it will be in a range, it needs a voltage regulator in front of the coils. Not finding a coil that can take from 100v-300v. Will look for it. Thanks for the solution again. I love it.